# unable to connect gpib instrument on ubuntu20.04.1

Tags: python, visa, gpib

I am using keysight 66319D and GPIB-USB on ubuntu20.04.1.
The driver for keysight has been installed successfully： iokerneldrivers-installer_20_0_26913_1.run and iolibrariessuite-installer_20_0_26913_1

However, when I use connection expert to connect 66319D, always connected fail.
[image: image description here]
Only "gpib1" can be selected for the GPIB interface id ;
The primary address must be "5" cause I press the "Address" button on panel is "5";
The secondary address is "none" cause not sured.
[image: image description here]
The test connection is failed and verify is failed too.
But I use it very smoothly under windows10.
[image: image description here]
[image: image description here]

I have been troubled by this question for two weeks. I hope I can get an answer as soon as possible. Thank you for your help~

Comment: Keysight has a 2021 version of IO Libraries that uses DKMS. If they did it right, it will be a little more robust than the 2020 version. It could be that you installed the Keysight libraries correctly. But if your operating system update the kernel afterward, then GPIB-USB would stop working. DKMS should fix this and automatically trigger a rebuild. Connection Expert should be able to find your GPIB-USB and if it doesn't, that is an indication that the installation did not go as smoothly as planned. Sometimes the [Keysight forums](https://community.keysight.com/forums/s) are good but not here.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.The version of ubuntu is also one of my concerns.I use ubuntu20.04(kernel 5.4) which is the version explicitly supported in ReadMe-IOLS2021-Linux.htm and disable kernel updates. But it also no works. I also asked for help on keysight Forums, but few questions will be answered.

Comment: Figure it out~ Disable secure boot is required to reinstall Ubuntu on the computer. Secure boot will affect the installation of third-party drivers. When iokerneldrivers and iolibrariessuite are successfully installed：$lsusb   Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0957:0718 Agilent Technologies, Inc. 82357B ()